# How to embed video in GTK+ application window using GStreamer & XOverlay?

Tags: c++, c, gtk, gstreamer

I am trying to write a small media player using GTK+ and GStreamer and currently using the XOverlay Interface to embed the video in a GtkDrawing Area **INSIDE** the mainwindow.

The program was compiled using this command:

```
g++ /home/phongcao/cacao.cc -o /home/phongcao/cacao `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 gstreamer-0.10 gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10 gstreamer-interfaces-0.10`
```

The problem is that the video was displayed in a **SEPARATED** window (instead of **under the toolbar** of the main window): 
 
[image: The video should be displayed under the mainwindow's toolbar]

Here is the source code of the program:

```
#include <gst/interfaces/xoverlay.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>

GstElement *play;
GtkAdjustment *progress;
GtkWidget *mainwindow, *drawingarea;

class TopWin
{
public:
  TopWin();
  ~TopWin();
  int Initialize(int argc, char *argv[]);
  int Execute();
  static void FileChooser(GtkButton *button, GtkWindow *mainwindow);
  static int Play(gchar *addr);
  static gboolean print_position(GstElement *element);
private:
};

TopWin::TopWin() {
}

TopWin::~TopWin() {
}

gboolean TopWin::print_position(GstElement *play) {
  GstFormat fmt = GST_FORMAT_TIME;
  gint64 pos, len;

  if (gst_element_query_position(play, &fmt, &pos) && gst_element_query_duration(play, &fmt, &len)) {
    g_print("Time: %" GST_TIME_FORMAT " / %" GST_TIME_FORMAT "\r", GST_TIME_ARGS(pos), GST_TIME_ARGS(len));

    gtk_adjustment_set_value(GTK_ADJUSTMENT(progress), (pos*100)/len);
  }

  return TRUE;
}

int TopWin::Play(gchar *addr) {
  GMainLoop *loop;
  GstBus *bus;

  loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

  play = gst_element_factory_make("playbin", "play");
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(play), "uri", addr, NULL);

  bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(play));
  gst_object_unref(bus);

  GstElement* x_overlay = gst_element_factory_make("xvimagesink", "videosink");

  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(play), "video-sink", x_overlay, NULL);

  gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_X_OVERLAY(x_overlay), GDK_WINDOW_XID(drawingarea->window));

  gst_element_set_state(play, GST_STATE_NULL);

  g_timeout_add(1000, (GSourceFunc) print_position, play);

  gtk_adjustment_set_value(GTK_ADJUSTMENT(progress), 0);

  gst_element_set_state(play, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  g_main_loop_run(loop);

  gst_element_set_state(play, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(play));

  gtk_widget_show_all(mainwindow);
  gtk_widget_realize(drawingarea);

  return 0;
}

void TopWin::FileChooser(GtkButton *button, GtkWindow *mainwindow) {
  GtkWidget *filechooser;
  gchar *uri;

  filechooser = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Open File...", mainwindow, GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN, GTK_STOCK_CANCEL, GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL, GTK_STOCK_OK, GTK_RESPONSE_OK, NULL);

  gtk_file_chooser_set_select_multiple(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(filechooser), FALSE);

  gint response = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(filechooser));

  if (response == GTK_RESPONSE_OK) {
    uri = gtk_file_chooser_get_uri(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(filechooser));
    gtk_widget_destroy(filechooser);
    Play(uri);
    g_free(uri);
  }
  else if (response == GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL) {
    gtk_widget_destroy(filechooser);
  }
}

int TopWin::Initialize(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GtkWidget *playbutton, *openbutton, *volumebutton;
  GtkWidget *prefbutton, *notebook;
  GtkWidget *vbox, *hbox;
  GtkWidget *entry, *hscale;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  gst_init(&argc, &argv);

  mainwindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(mainwindow), 0);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(mainwindow), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  playbutton = gtk_button_new();
  gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(playbutton), gtk_image_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_PLAY, GTK_ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR));

  openbutton = gtk_button_new();
  gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(openbutton), gtk_image_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_OPEN, GTK_ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR));
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(openbutton), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(TopWin::FileChooser), (gpointer) mainwindow);

  volumebutton = gtk_button_new();
  gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(volumebutton), gtk_image_new_from_file("volume.png"));

  prefbutton = gtk_button_new();
  gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(prefbutton), gtk_image_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_EXECUTE, GTK_ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR));

  entry = gtk_entry_new();

  progress = GTK_ADJUSTMENT(gtk_adjustment_new(0.00, 0.00, 100.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.00));

  hscale = gtk_hscale_new(progress);
  gtk_scale_set_draw_value(GTK_SCALE(hscale), FALSE);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(hscale, 200, NULL);

  hbox = gtk_hbox_new(FALSE, 0);
  drawingarea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);

  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), openbutton, FALSE, FALSE, 2);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), playbutton, FALSE, FALSE, 2);

  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), hscale, FALSE, FALSE, 2);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), volumebutton, FALSE, FALSE, 2);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), entry, TRUE, TRUE, 2);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), prefbutton, FALSE, FALSE, 2);

  gtk_button_set_relief(GTK_BUTTON(playbutton), GTK_RELIEF_NONE);
  gtk_button_set_relief(GTK_BUTTON(openbutton), GTK_RELIEF_NONE);
  gtk_button_set_relief(GTK_BUTTON(volumebutton), GTK_RELIEF_NONE);
  gtk_button_set_relief(GTK_BUTTON(prefbutton), GTK_RELIEF_NONE);

  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), hbox, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), drawingarea, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(mainwindow), vbox);

  gtk_widget_show_all(mainwindow);

  gtk_widget_realize(drawingarea);

  return 0;
}

int TopWin::Execute() {
  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  int result = 0;
  TopWin* topwin = new TopWin();

  if (0 == topwin->Initialize(argc, argv)) {
    result = topwin->Execute();
  }

  delete topwin;

  return result;
}
```

Thank you for helping me with this problem! I have spent almost 3 days scratching over my head for this. The XOverlay reference on GStreamer website is so confusing... :(

Please tell me if you need any additional information... Thank you!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
GstElement* x_overlay=gst_element_factory_make ("xvimagesink", "videosink");
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(play),"video-sink",x_overlay,NULL);
gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_X_OVERLAY(x_overlay), GDK_WINDOW_XID(drawingarea->window));
```

Create new XV video sink. Set it as video sink of your playbin. Attach xv video sink to your drawingarea window ID. You also need to add `drawingarea` to some container before that.

Your program produces warnings and gtk errors, they may be source of some of your problems better fix them.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I already edited the code above according to what you said. Then I compiled the source and got this error: 

"/home/phongcao/cacao.cc:61: error: ‘gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle’ was not declared in this scope". Not sure if this is a bug of GStreamer or my fault... Can you please copy paste the code above and try to compile on your machine to see if GStreamer works... Thank you very much Banthar!!

Comment: @phngcv: It works fine for me. Try updating your GStreamer or change this function to `gst_x_overlay_set_xwindow_id`. If that doesn't help, open `gst/interfaces/xoverlay.h` and check what functions are declared.

Comment: Just to warn you the line `gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_X_OVERLAY(x_overlay), GDK_WINDOW_XID(drawingarea->window));` is not thread safe. You need to put a handler on the realize signal to get the xid with `GDK_WINDOW_XID(drawingarea->window);` save that value and the use it later with `gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle`.

Answer (score 2):

`gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle` interface is deprecated now in recent gstreamer library. New interface is `gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle`. A simple supplementation can be sited from https://web.archive.org/web/20190628124320/http://wikistack.com/how-to-make-your-own-media-player-in-linux-using-gtk-and-gstreamer/