# Media player using gstreamer - wrong behavior when playing a second media

Tags: c++, gtk, gstreamer

I'm googling around in order to use gstreamer library in my c++ programm (a media player). I looked to these links:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078368/how-to-embed-video-in-gtk-application-window-using-gstreamer-xoverlay), [2](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+5%3A+GUI+toolkit+integration), [3](https://github.com/felipec/gst-player/). At this point I'm able to open a media file and play it within a drawing area. Anyway, when I again want to play another media, it is opened in a different newly window.

I'm getting crazy for this because references are very incomplete and I found few things on google.

This is my "playMedia" function:

```
void MediaPlayer::playMedia(const string &filename) {

    gst_element_set_state(playerData.playbin2, GST_STATE_READY);
    gchar *uri = g_filename_to_uri(filename.c_str(),NULL,NULL);
    if (uri) {
        g_object_set(playerData.playbin2, "uri", uri, NULL);
        g_object_set(G_OBJECT(playerData.videosink), "force-aspect-ratio", TRUE, NULL);
        g_free(uri);
        gtk_widget_realize(areaPlayer); ì
        play();
    } 
}
```

and this is the "play" function:

```
void MediaPlayer::play() {

    state = PLAYING;
    gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(buttonPlayPause), imgPause);
    g_object_ref(imgPause);

    gst_element_set_state(playerData.playbin2, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

}
```

**Additions**

Here is the part of code where I define the areaPlayer (gtk_drawing_area):

```
gst_init(0, 0);
playerData.playbin2 = gst_element_factory_make("playbin2", NULL);
playerData.videosink = gst_element_factory_make ("xvimagesink", NULL);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(playerData.playbin2), "video-sink", playerData.videosink, NULL);

playerData.duration = GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE;

areaPlayer = gtk_drawing_area_new();
gtk_widget_set_double_buffered (areaPlayer, FALSE);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(theWidget), areaPlayer, true, true, 0);
g_signal_connect(areaPlayer, "realize", G_CALLBACK(this->playerRealize), this); 
g_signal_connect(areaPlayer, "draw", G_CALLBACK(this->playerDraw), this);
```

Here is the realize function

```
void MediaPlayer::playerRealize(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) { 

    MediaPlayer *m = (MediaPlayer *)data;

    GdkWindow *window = gtk_widget_get_window(widget);
    guintptr window_handle;

    if (!gdk_window_ensure_native(window))
        cout << "Couldn't create native window needed for GstXOverlay!" << endl;

    // Retrieve window handler from GDK
    window_handle = GDK_WINDOW_XID(window);

    // Pass it to playbin2, which implements XOverlay and will forward it to the video sink

    gst_x_overlay_set_xwindow_id (GST_X_OVERLAY (m->playerData.videosink), window_handle);

}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `gtk_widget_realize()`? And what's the code that creates `areaPlayer`?

Comment: @andlabs just added the part where I create areaPlayer. I call gtk_widget_realize() as it is done in Basic Tutorial 5 in the gstreamer SDK, but actually I don't really know why...

Comment: See what I'm wondering is if you get a new window because your code is actually creating a new window and you aren't realizing it. The only way I can confirm this is if I know that you recreate the `areaPlayer` and its parent window each time you open a new file... How do you open a new file, and what is the full function of the signal handler for that operation? That being said, I'm not familiar with the GStreamer tutorial, so beyond what I just asked I can only forward this question to other people; sorry.

Comment: @andlabs thanks for your attention! No, I don't recreate areaPlayer. I've posted now the realize function of areaPlayer.